# How to iterate through DataFrame rows and grab values from dicts in cols?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

[Features_Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wln9.png)

Each feature frame will be a batch of data. I would like to extract all values for the key 'coordinates' in the col geometry and iteratively insert into another df.

With that same df, I would also like to store data extracted from the properties col. Properties col has many keys.

Each source frame will have both 'geometry':'coordinates' and 'properties', which will consists of various keys.

Each col in this new DataFrame will be a key inside either 'geometry' or 'properties'.

For example:

```
      coordinates          name
0      [-108.600,39.09]    'Target'
1      [51.459,82.04]      'Costco'
2      [-35.459,82.04]     'BJ's Wholesale Club'
3      [98.459,12.07]      'Walgreens'
4      [105.404,96.04]     'Walmart
```

I can access both cols with the below:

```
coord_frame = features_frame['geometry'][:]
properties_frame = features_frame['properties'][:]
```

But that only splits the frame in two. Typically, if I did:

```
Feature_Frame['geometry'][:]['coordinates']
```

I'd get the values for the coordinates key in the geometry col for all rows, if I did:

```
Feature_Frame['properties'][:]['name']
```

I'd get the value for the name key in the properties col for all rows.

Instead I just get a key error saying name or coordinates dont exist.

Comment: It would be easy to provide an answer Instead of image into text data. Please paste your dataframe as editable text data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Feed list of dicts to `pd.DataFrame` constructor

`pd.Series.apply` is a Python-level loop, except that it usually *underperforms* a simple list comprehension. A much better idea is to use the optimised code used in the `pd.DataFrame` constructor. Here's an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'geometry': [{'coordinates': [-108.600,39.09], 'name': 'Target'},
                                {'coordinates': [51.459,82.04], 'name': 'Costco'}]})

print(df)

                                            geometry
0  {'coordinates': [-108.6, 39.09], 'name': 'Targ...
1  {'coordinates': [51.459, 82.04], 'name': 'Cost...

res = pd.DataFrame(df['geometry'].values.tolist())

print(res)

       coordinates    name
0  [-108.6, 39.09]  Target
1  [51.459, 82.04]  Costco
```

#### Use `concat` for multiple series of dictionaries

The above can be extended to arbitrary series of dictionaries:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'geometry': [{'coordinates': [-108.600,39.09], 'name': 'Target'},
                                {'coordinates': [51.459,82.04], 'name': 'Costco'}],
                   'properties': [{'osm_id': 288700723, 'osm_tye': 'W'},
                                  {'osm_id': 52734154, 'osm_tye': 'W'}]})

res = pd.concat((pd.DataFrame(df[col].values.tolist()) for col in df), axis=1)

print(res)

       coordinates    name     osm_id osm_tye
0  [-108.6, 39.09]  Target  288700723       W
1  [51.459, 82.04]  Costco   52734154       W
```

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame()
```

and then e.g.

```
df_new['coordinates'] = features_frame['geometry'].apply(lambda x: x['coordinates'])
```

or

```
df_new['name'] = features_frame['properties'].apply(lambda x: x['name'])
```

And if you want to do that with all keys you can just loop over the keys of exemplary the dict in the first row:

```
for key in features_frame.geometry[0]:
    df_new[key] = features_frame.geometry.apply(lambda x: x[key])

for key in features_frame.properties[0]:
    df_new[key] = features_frame.properties.apply(lambda x: x[key])
```

---

*supplemental:*
...and just in case there are identical keys in the `geometry`- and the `properties`-dicts, you could easily decorate them when creating new columns to prevent overwriting:

```
for ...
    df_new['geom_' + key] = ...
for ...
    df_new['prop_' + key] = ...
```

---

**EDIT:**

In case that some dictionaries in a column don't have all keys, a default value, e.g. `None` should be returned.
To achieve that, simply use the `get`-method, which allow for defining a default value, in the lambda functions instead of indexing:

```
lambda x: x.get(key, None)
```

This is at least a proper solution against key errors.
However, if the code doesn't iterate through all keys because the dict in the first row is not representative for all dicts, at first a list of all keys has to be created.
And there are different possibilities to get to this list:

1. Ideally you already know all the keys from elsewhere. Then you can put them in a list and iterate over it instead of the first dict.
2. Perhaps you know that there is at least one dict with the most keys and that this longest dict has all keys and the keys of shorter dicts in the same column are always subsets. Then you can find the

   ```
   longest_dict = sorted(df.geometry, key=len)[-1]
   ```
3. Perhaps you know nothing at all about the keys. So you have to collect all different keys which appear anywhere in a column:

   ```
   all_keys = []
   for d in df.geometry:
       all_keys.extend(d)
   all_keys = set(all_keys)
   ```

Comment: Thats perfect, thank you. But how do I apply that lambda to all rows in features_frame.properties?

Comment: I don't quite get your question - did you try the code and there were rows lacking in df_new? Normally `apply` works on all rows of a dataframe.

Comment: For example, not all rows have the key 'housenumber'. If I do the above then I get a KeyError: 'housenumber', I've done a try/except but then the 'housenumber' data of all the other rows get dropped. So I guess my question is...how do I account for the first row not always having the same keys as every other row?